# sklearn: when to use one-hot encoding / range of output variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, one-hot-encoding

I have a simple code, which has the input features in X and the output labels in y, where each y_i is in the set {1,2,3,4}. I want to use SVM or Logistic Regression in sklearn for classification. My question is: when does sklearn require one-hot encoding? If I use SVM, will y be fine as it is or does SVM only handle boolean outputs? Also, it is extremely frustrating that no documentation in sklearn (SVM or Logistic Regression) specifies the range of the valid outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ok. In sklearn [the label encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) usually encodes it as 0,1,2,3 if your class labels are say a,b,c,d. Onehot encoding is normally used for transforming your independent variable.

What you are looking for is multi-class classification. It is implemented in both [svm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) and [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sparse_logistic_regression_20newsgroups.html).

We use the iris dataset as an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
data = sns.load_dataset('iris')
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,LabelEncoder

data.head()
Out[5]: 
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa

y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['species'])+1
pd.value_counts(y)
Out[42]: 
1    50
2    50
3    50


X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data.iloc[:,:4])
```

Now fit the logistic:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression().fit(X,y)

# confusion matrix
pd.crosstab(lr.predict(X) , y)

col_0   1   2   3
row_0            
1      50   0   0
2       0  47   1
3       0   3  49
```

And svm:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC().fit(X, y)
pd.crosstab(clf.predict(X) , y)

col_0   1   2   3
row_0            
1      50   0   0
2       0  48   2
3       0   2  48
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Instead of SVM or Logistic, if you had a single perceptron, since it has a linear decision boundary and cannot learn more than 2 labels, I assume sklearn's implementation of that necessarily requires boolean outputs/labels? (By boolean output i mean, y_i belongs to some set of size 2)